# Call a third party app from another app

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to launch any iPhone/iPad application from within another app?
For example in my application if I want the user to read a document say a pdf file from any of the installed apps on iphone or an ipad say PDFReaderLite.
How can i launch this app from my app.

How can we know which all installed apps support reading of documents and show a list to open with any of these apps from my app?

How do we get the URL Schemes for the installed apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the UIDocumentInteractionController to show a list with installed apps that can handle the file.

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *controller = [[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
[controller presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:someBarItem animated:YES];
```

This shows a list of all apps that are registered for the filetype and opens an app if the user selects one.